# Two association proxies using set and list as a collection_class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

[Association Proxy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html) is an SQLALchemy extension which enables proxying attributes from one ORM class to another using an aggregate collection, deduced from the relationship type.

I wish to have two association proxies to my table `Item`, one for attribute `class_` and one for attribute `object_` (named such in this example to give you an intuition that multiple objects correspond to one class). Now, I wish to have a set of classes named `classes` and a list named `objects` in my ORM object corresponding to table `ItemsGroup`. Can I have that?

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class ItemsGroup(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    items = db.relationship("Item")

    # I want this proxy to be represented as a set
    classes = association_proxy('items', 'class_')   
    # and this to be represented as a list
    objects = association_proxy('items', 'object_')

class Item(db.Model):
    group_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(ItemsGroup.id))

    class_ = db.Column(db.Enum('Class I', 'Class 'II', 'Class III'))
    object_ = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

Now, I understand that this table schema is not ideal (not normalized). I also understand that this may not play well if we attempted to modify the proxied values (when modifying a value accessed through `ItemsGroup.classes` we would not know which `Item.class_` to modify). But I am interested in doing that anyway.

I could set the relationship's `collection_class=set` but then the `objects` would no longer be a list. I naively tried setting `creator=set` in the association proxy, but it did not work either.

Is that possible or do I need to create a hybrid property instead? If there is a trick to make this work, would it be preferred over the hybrid property?